# passing the props value to the url in axios is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to send the varaible to the url of axios but doing so it provide me the error 404 and even '{' braces are changed to '%' on error

import Axios from 'axios'
export default {

```
mounted(){
    this.$parent.$on('create_new_lesson',(seriesId)=>{
       this.seriesId = seriesId

        $('#createLesson').modal()
    })
},
data()
{
    return{
        title:'',
        description:'',
        episode_number:'',
        video_id:'',
        seriesId:''
    }
},

methods:{
   createLesson()
   {
    Axios.post('/admin/${this.seriesId}/lessons',{
        title:this.title,
        description:this.description,
        episode_number:this.episode_number,
        video_id:this.video_id
     }).then(resp =>{
       console.log(resp)
     }). catch(resp =>{
       console.log(resp)
     })
   }
}
```

}

it should return send the created data to the console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKqP.png)

Comment: try the traditional concatenation `'/admin/'+this.seriesId+'/lessons'`

Comment: thank you for your response  the below worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For string interpolation you need to use backticks `` ` `` instead of single quotes `'`:

```es6
`/admin/${this.seriesId}/lessons`
```